# jstl cannot be found though correctly placed

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jstl

Unfortunately after very long time i'm re-posting again about the same problem:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

The first time i solved it by just placing jstl-1.2 in web-inf/lib, this time i cannot get, in any way, why this is not working.

The "funny" thing is that i have plenty of other projects which are up and running, with exactly the same configuration tree:
/web-inf/lib/jstl-1.2.jar

no reference of these jars in web-xml, they are simply in the web-apps-libraries

The app runs fine, but as soon as i insert the taglib line in the page i'm requesting:
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

i get the exception,

do you have any advice? the taglib is ok "copied from a working project"
the classpath are fine, the web-app libraries too

thank you, have no idea how to solve this after 5 hours working on it.

Comment: I suspect you've run into the problem mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845776/jstl-taglib-uri-is-obsolete

Comment: Yep, make sure you're defined w/ the correct servlet spec version. You may also need standard.jar depending on what implementation you're using.

Comment: this is the problem, i cant find any issue in configurations, the web app version in web.xml is 2.5, all jars are in the right spot.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? If so which? Is the JAR file also really in the IDE-deployed WAR/folder?

Comment: This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31043869/intellij-and-jsp-jstl-cannot-resolve-taglib-for-jstl-in-tomcat7/32444393#32444393

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I dealt with this problem. I used to do dev way out in the country where I often did not have 'Net connectivity. You must set the uri in the tablib line to a location which can be found...at run-time. You can point to a local copy. I think I set an actual file system location in the uri. However, can't remember that detail (and am not near the right computer to verify coding around this issue).